# Code changes behavior after upgrading sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to optimized my app for iOs 7 but still target iOS 6.

I had 2 textfield for email input to validate, but it fails.

I did it like that:

```
    if ([email.text isEqualToString:confirm_email.text]) {
    //process
    }
    else{
    //display mismatch error
   UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email mismatch"
                                                         message:@"Your email does not match the confirmation!"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
    }
```

Now it does not work in iOS 6 but only iOS 7 , it display the error.
I didnt really touch the code, Im not sure why the behavior changed.

Comment: Paste information about an error - put breakpoint and give us more info about what went wrong in execution of that code.

Comment: its not a compiler error, I just display an alertBox stating that they wont match

Comment: Try NSLog both on .text variables - maybe one of them is nil.

Comment: I just Log them they are both `(null)`, why is that

Comment: @downvoters, at least comment so I can improve my question

Comment: I don't even know what "email" is or "confirm_email" - so how can I help you. Paste more code and explain where those are coming from.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I mentionned that they are Textfield read carefully, but anyway it is now solved, thanks you though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `UITextField` doesn't have any user text it returns `nil` on iOS 7 but the empty string (`@""`) on iOS 6.  The behavior you are seeing is because if either text field in `[email.text isEqualToString:confirm_email.text]` is `nil` it will always evaluate to `NO`.

Comment: this makes sense, but how do you explain that it was working fine on iOS 6 untill I upgrade the sdk?

Comment: Compiling with the iOS 6 SDK and running on iOS 7 uses a special compatibility mode (which worked with your current logic), however compiling with the iOS 7 SDK skips this mode and puts you into the iOS 7 logic (which is returning `nil`).